# how to use Conj function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to achieve one of the functions in my program. I have list=[a b c] as a parameter in func3. I want to test an equality of these items. If they are not equal I will call it again using another list return from func2. 
Here is what I need to do. I want the Conj to do this [list list1 list2 list3] until func3 have the items that are equal. In my function, I want conj to merge an empty vector r[] to other lists when the condition is false.All I get right now is a final list return when the condition is true. Assume that the condition must be false(items are not equal) before getting true. Can someone help me to use the conj in the false condition.Thank you.

```
   ;input [1 2 3]
   ;output [[1 2 3][1 3 4] [3 4 5] ]// numbers for demo only
   (defn func3 [list]
       (loop [v (vec list) r []]
        (if(= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))        
            (conj r v)
            (let[result (func2 v)]
            ;i want to merge result to r until the condition is true
            (conj r result)
            (func3 result)))))
```

Comment: Seriously you must better describe what your function is supposed to do. Giving it a more meaningful name than `func3` would be a start. And then I wonder how your function ever returns lists with unequal items and more than one.

Comment: Here is what i am trying to do. func3 will determine whether items in [1 2 3 4] are equal. If not, func2 will calculate a new list and return in to func3. func3 does its job again until it finds the equal items in the list. I want to print out the result from each calculation of func2 including the  initial list. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you have a list of three elements as an initial input, want to compare them for equality. In case they match, you want to append the list to a later returned accumulator - in case they don't, you want to transform the list using a function idiomatically called `func2` and try that procedure again.

EDIT: Since you have commented how your function should work, here comes an implementation:

```
(defn func3
  "Determines whether items in coll are equal. If not, transforms coll with func2 and
   repeats the test until a coll with equal elements could be found. 

   Returns a vector of all tried versions."
  [coll]
  (loop [acc []
         coll coll]
    (if (apply = coll)
      (conj acc coll)
      (recur (conj acc coll)
             (func2 coll)))))
```

Here is a lazy implementation:

```
 (defn func3
   [coll]
   (-> (->> coll
            (iterate func2)
            (split-with (partial apply =)))
       (as-> [dropped [r]]
             (concat dropped [r])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Conj never changes its input, it creates a new output based on the input. In the second condition, you are not doing anything to the output of conj, so its result is never used.

```
 (defn func3 [list]
       (loop [[v & vs] (vec list) r []]
        (if (= (v 0) (v 1) (v 2))        
            (conj r v)
            (let [result (func2 v)
                  r (conj r result)]
              (recur vs r)))))
```

Comment: What input/output is to be expected from that function?

Comment: good point, I was just addressing the question about conj, and clearly there are more issues here (like loop being used as if it were let) I assume there is a recur missing here, but I don't know where it goes.

Comment: updated based on the comment in the question to put a recur in the appropriate place

Comment: That is why i am using r[] which will merge result in it. And return r later. I try this in the console and it works: (def x (conj x [1 2])). This will return X as [[1 2] [1 2]]

Comment: yes, because that binds the output, just using conj does not bind the result, it needs a binding that you can refer to. Also r [] is a loop binding, but you were not recurring to the loop, so no value was ever coming in there other than the initialization, and with the explicit recur on func3 the conj output was not being used.

Comment: I could use recur but it does work fine without it. The point to conj the result from func2 into r.

Comment: if you don't use recur, don't use loop, loop is just a misnamed let without recur

Comment: Btw, Why the Recur func has two parameters. I don't understand. Are U recurring func3 or something else? And what is [v&vs] being used?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40601/discussion-between-user1874435-and-noisesmith)

Comment: Thank you every one, I got it.